# Have a canon T6 rebel? what extra equipment should i get if i want to get more professional photos?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation

could you please provide actual equipment for for example flash diffusrs, or sppedlights, etc, this would be to end up photographing kids, newborns, couples in a mini studio and also outside photography

Comment: Skills. Easy to order, but delivery of the whole set can take a few years :)

Answer (score 2):

The way to get more professional photos is to learn how to use what you already have. Once you reach the point where you know how to do something that you don't have the equipment to do, you'll know what it is you need.

A good introductory course for flash photography is [Lighting 101](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101.html) at [Strobist](http://strobist.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This question is too board, and will most likely be closed for that.

I just hope your camera has a lens and a memory card. If it does, you have enough gear for now.

But I can tell you need to do some homework, starting with searching for example on this same forum some tags, Lightning, portrait, composition, landscape, or whatever topic you want to do.

But the main point is that you do not need extra-nothing to take "more professional photos" if you do not start taking "amateur photos"... whatever those terms mean.

You need to explore and learn how to be a critic of your own work. If you want to spend money on gear and not use it, and not use your observation skills, you will get nowhere.

Use a window, use a cardboard box, use the garage door, go outside early, go outside late, at day, at night, the extra gear you need, for now, are your feet (or a wheelchair if the case), and move!

Answer (score 0):

Learning how to and successfully controlling the light you use to make a photo is what photography is all about. Got a camera and a lens? Good, you can start this journey.

First, take photos in good ol' natural light. Do portraits in the morning glow, at dusk, in the middle of the day, in the sun, in the shade. Analyze how the light bounces around your scene. Analyze your own photographs.

Now, add a reflector into the mix. This gives you just 1 extra source of light that you can control. Bounce it where you want it to add just a touch of extra light where and how you want it. Get comfortable with this.

Now, add a flash into the mix. Use it as a fill light - natural is still your key. When you want to up the ante, reverse things. Use the strobe as your main light, natural light as fill.

At the same time, you can work on your studio work. In this environment, you need to control everything. Start with 1 main key light and a reflector. Use different sized soft boxes and learn how this affects things. Study portraits of others and try to replicate them, using the exact same lighting.

It's easy to go overboard on gear, and the fact is, you can't do studio work without a strobe. But, the trick is to pace yourself. Start small and learn to use what you have. Only then do you want to spend more money.